# Распознавание текста с изображений

Tags: android, java

Существуют ли библиотеки для распознования (получения) текста с изображений?

Comment: Да, существуют. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr) есть некоторое кол-во примеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine 4.0 for Android](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/android)
- [tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) - библиотека на C/C++ (поддерживается Google)

Answer (score 1):

Я в свое время пользовался [**`JavaOCR`**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/?_test=beta), которая почему-то не указана в ответе на `stackoverflow.com`. Библиотека сама по себе лучше врапперов над `Tesseract` и очень удобна в применении.

*Более того, она все еще активно развивается.*

Comment: Ну вообще делается софт для поиска определенного текста с картинки. Ну это уже можно сделать имея исходный.